# Did I install the wrong generic kernel?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, lts

I am using 14.04.5 LTS in a production environment.

I think that I might have installed the kernel for Xenial when I am using Trusty. If I did, I'm surprised apt let me do this..

The system seems to be working fine and has been since I set it up. The thing is I see these package updates in landscape, and when I do the usual apt-get update && upgrade I see this when I get to the upgrade step:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-generic-lts-xenial linux-headers-generic
  linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial linux-image-generic
  linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
```

When I login, landscape-sysinfo shows me this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-109-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Wed Jul 11 11:29:48 CDT 2018

  System load:  1.68                Processes:           156
  Usage of /:   16.1% of 241.77GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 3%                  IP address for eth0: 10.0.0.0.
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

17 packages can be updated.
16 updates are security updates.

New release '16.04.4 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

When I check the kernels with:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

I see this:

```
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-110-generic       3.13.0-110.157
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-139-generic       3.13.0-139.188
rc  linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic         4.2.0-27.32~14.04.1
ii  linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic         4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic        4.4.0-109.132~14.04.1
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic         4.4.0-64.85~14.04.1
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-110-generic 3.13.0-110.157
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-139-generic 3.13.0-139.188
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic   4.2.0-27.32~14.04.1
ii  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic   4.2.0-42.49~14.04.1
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic  4.4.0-109.132~14.04.1
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic   4.4.0-64.85~14.04.1
ii  linux-image-generic                  3.13.0.139.148
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-trusty       3.13.0.153.163
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-wily         4.2.0.42.34
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-xenial       4.4.0.109.92
```

I am wondering if I should install the 3.13.0.153.163 kernel and if that will get rid of the "kept back" messages about Xenial..

Will this be safe?

EDIT:

I found where I got these instructions from originally:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

They state to use the Xenial kernel for the LTS release of 14.04... confusing. I remember this is what I did.

Was this correct?

Comment: Nope, you did not install the incorrect kernel.  That is how the Hardware Enablement Stack works.  From that page:  "stacks provide newer kernel and X support for existing Ubuntu LTS releases. "  Try running `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to get rid of those held back messages.

Comment: whew.. that's good to know. At least I didn't follow some incorrect instructions. I've never run dirt-upgrade on a production server. I usually just build a new server. Have you ever done this one a production server? If so, what's your experience been?

Comment: I've not done it on a production server here as that is not my department at my job.  However, anytime there is a kernel update the host should be restarted.  You might want to look into Canonical Livepatch that allows for hot fixes or patches to be applied on the fly without a reboot.  Normally with servers you tend to keep with the kernel that is working as rebooting a server causes downtime.  The livepatch service can at least help with vulnerabilities that might need to be patched instantly.

Comment: I noticed that when I test-installed bionic beaver, version 18. Very interested in that feature. Thanks :)

Comment: I am going to add one more thing here.  When you see `The following have been kept back` that is when you should be running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.  That will not upgrade your version from 14.04 to 16.04.  What that will do is actually install the kernels and files that are used for the next point release like 14.04.5

Comment: That's incredible. I didn't know that. I had thought this notice was to prompt users to move to the next distribution.. Thanks.  I'll have to setup a vm and do a little testing with that. I've never used that option before.